# How to create sudo rules to access non-root local accounts that prevent any action being taken on a specific file?

Tags: linux, sudo

I have the following rule set that allows a group to run any command as user "apache":

```
%Test_team ALL=(apache)  NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I want to limit the ability to run any command (cat/cp/rm/vi, etc) on this file so as to keep its contents secure. I can do this for a single command like this:

```
%Test_team ALL=(apache)  NOPASSWD: !/bin/cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.bak
```

How can I do this for all commands? Is it possible?

Comment: Set the file permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict access to a file with `sudo`.

You won't be able to enumerate all possible commands that may allow access to that file, especially if you allow access to a shell. `sudo` configuration is based on the commands that are to be executed, not on files that may or may not be accessed by those commands.

You can try to allow a single command with `sudo` that sets up a SELinux context that doesn't allow access to that specific file. All processes started by that command would be restricted.